# LLVM bytecode linked with with ld.lld gives segmentation fault

Tags: llvm

I wrote a simple C program:

example.c:

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Then converted it to .ll by using

```
clang -S -emit-llvm example.c
```

Which generated a example.ll file which looks like this:

```
; ModuleID = 'example.c'
source_filename = "example.c"
target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone uwtable
define dso_local i32 @main() #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4
  ret i32 0
}

attributes #0 = { noinline nounwind optnone uwtable "correctly-rounded-divide-sqrt-fp-math"="false" "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "min-legal-vector-width"="0" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="true" "no-frame-pointer-elim-non-leaf" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-jump-tables"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "no-signed-zeros-fp-math"="false" "no-trapping-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }

!llvm.module.flags = !{!0}
!llvm.ident = !{!1}

!0 = !{i32 1, !"wchar_size", i32 4}
!1 = !{!"clang version 8.0.0-3 (tags/RELEASE_800/final)"}
```

Then I converted .ll file to .o by using:

```
llc -filetype=obj example.ll
```

And then I tried to link that file to make it executable by using:

```
ld.lld example.o -o example -e main
```

Which created an executable ./example.

Running example yields a segmentation fault

```
29185 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./example
```

objdump of example.o looks like this:

```
example.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
   b:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
   d:   5d                      pop    %rbp
   e:   c3                      retq
```

And the executable looks like this:

```
example:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000201000 <main>:
  201000:   55                      push   %rbp
  201001:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  201004:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
  20100b:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  20100d:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  20100e:   c3                      retq
```

I also tried linking the object file with **ld** but that also didn't work. Am I missing something. How can I make a llvm object file executable? Please note that none of the commands yielded any errors or warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is not how you supposed to link the executable. E.g. entry point is supposed to be named "_start" and so on, so you're missing bunch of runtime initialization objects / libraries here.

Either link with clang (so, `clang example.ll` or `clang example.o`) or pass -v to clang invocation to obtain the proper linker cmdline.